# How to disable the focus of listheader and footer?

Tags: android

I am working on android applications. In my page I kept listheader,listview and listfooter. I had disabled the focus of listview but when i am trying to disable the header and footer it is not appying ?

MyCode:

For listview I had disabled the focus by giving

```
lvAdapter adapter = new lvAdapter(this,list){
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false; }

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
return false;      }    };
```

**listheader.xml** 
I have changed in my xml file by giving **focusable=false** in **textview**

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textSize="12dip" >
    </TextView>
```

**listfooter.xml** 
I have changed in my xml file by giving **focusable=false** in **textview**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textSize="12dip" >
</TextView>
```

But even then the focus of header and footer had not disabled. Pleae help me regarding this
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding Header you can use

[`public void addHeaderView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)

as

```
listview.addHeaderView(view, null, false);
```

Same way for adding Footer also

[`public void addFooterView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)

as

```
listview.addFooterView(view, null, false);
```